# Spring Security config - 403 forbidden

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, basic-authentication

I Use spring 5.0.7.RELEASE and I need to add basic authentication for my spring application and this is a pretty old application. That is why it uses the old way of registering the config classes. I have added the `SecurityConfig` class and imported it in the `SpringMvcConfig` as shown below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {
        "com.test" },
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter( Configuration.class )
        } )
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring-context.xml")
@EnableSwagger2
@Import({SwaggerConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class})
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private static final String[] RESOURCE_BUNDLES = new String[] { "MessageResources" };
    private static final String[] YAML_RESOURCE_BUNDLES = new String[] { "messages" };

    /**
     * Configures the Jackson object mapper
     */
    @Bean( name = "objectMapper" )
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper( JacksonService jacksonService ) {
        return jacksonService.getObjectMapper();
    }

    /**
     * Configures the ApplicationContextProvider
     */
    @Bean( name = "applicationContextProvider" )
    public ApplicationContextProvider getApplicationContextProvider() {
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    }
}
```

and here is the web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.SpringMvcConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

 <!-- Spring Security Configuration -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and here is my `SecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test")
                .password("testpwd")
                .roles("USER");
    }

}
```

I get a 403 forbidden The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. I also added

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with this `@Import(value = { SecurityConfig.class })` in your main class

Comment: I tried this, what is happening is that on start up the class is kicking in but my authentication is still not working, which means that I can access my end points with out the username and password

Comment: So you need to create delegating  filter proxy chain in web.xml with creating a WebAppIntializer class which extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer this example would help you https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-mvc-security-login-logout

Comment: hmm. tried this but no luck so far

Comment: Aren't you missing the `springSecurityFilterChain` servlet filter? I don't see it anywhere in your configuration.

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: your web.xml is not right with tags